# Why is Flurl response empty when fetching lyricsify.com?

Tags: flurl

I want to use [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) to query [lyricsify.com](https://lyricsify.com)
but I always get an empty string as result.

With Insomnia, Powershell and other tools, I get the HTML response as expected.

```
[Fact]
public async void FlurlTest()
{
    string googleResponse = await "https://www.google.com".GetStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine($"googleResponse: {googleResponse}");
    // works as expected
    Assert.NotEmpty(googleResponse);
    
    string lyricsifyResponse = await "https://www.lyricsify.com".GetStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine($"lyricsifyResponse: {lyricsifyResponse}");
    // fails
    Assert.NotEmpty(lyricsifyResponse);
}
```

- I checked the response object, it has status code 200 OK.
- I checked redirects, which are enabled.

Any ideas? Did I miss something peculiar that lyricsify.com is doing?
Do I need to configure anything in Flurl to get the expected web page as response?

Comment: I'm the author of Flurl, I confirmed this myself, and I honestly can't say why it's happening. If you do a `GetAsync` instead of `GetStringAsync`, you'll get an object that includes the response headers. I suspect `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` may have something to do with it but I'm not certain. I also confirmed `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` also returns an empty body. If you post a new question specific to HttpClient instead of Flurl, you'll reach a broader audience and may get a more helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this issue. I just opened a question for `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76333609/why-is-httpclient-getstringasync-response-empty-when-fetching-lyricsify-com)

Comment: Nice, and I see you already got an answer that wouldn't have occurred to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites expect the `User-Agent` header. Just pass some random value like this:

```cs
string lyricsifyResponse = await "https://www.lyricsify.com"
    .WithHeader("user-agent", "FlurlTest")
    .GetStringAsync();
```

Looks like Insomnia, Powershell and other tools set the `user-agent` header by default.