# Why is HttpClient.GetStringAsync response empty when fetching lyricsify.com?

Tags: c#, http

I want to use [GetStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=net-8.0) to query [lyricsify.com](https://www.lyricsify.com) but I always get an empty string as result.

With Insomnia, Powershell and other tools, I get the HTML response as expected.

```
[Fact]
public async void HttpClientTest()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string googleResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com");
    Debug.WriteLine($"googleResponse: {googleResponse}");
    // works as expected
    Assert.NotEmpty(googleResponse);

    string lyricsifyResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.lyricsify.com");
    Debug.WriteLine($"lyricsifyResponse: {lyricsifyResponse}");
    // fails
    Assert.NotEmpty(lyricsifyResponse);
}
```

- I checked the response object, it has status code 200 OK.
- I checked redirects, which are enabled.

Any ideas?
Did I miss something peculiar that lyricsify.com is doing?
Do I need to configure anything in the HttpClient to get the expected web page as response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some websites expected to pass `User-Agent`, so only pass some random values as `User-Agent` like this:

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "some-thing");

// rest of code
```

Comment: This did the trick. Looks like Insomnia, Powershell etc. send the `user-agent` header by default. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A header can be added to the request.
As follows;

```
request.Headers.Add("HeaderName","Value");
```

You can also test this with Postman.

Comment: It sure can, but how that fixes the issue?

Comment: You can add this header or cookie while making a request, Postman also gives you the code output. You can look at this  The request may be incompletely transmitted to the other party.